# How can I create an animation like background in Windows Phone 7 using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

In my application, I want to add a background animation for the background (it's black).

I don't know, something simple like appears from the bottom to top some burbles, ballons, etc.. Sorry, I have no idea about to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use WPF on Windows Phone. You can use Silverlight which is similar. You could also use XNA, especially on Mango.

Comment: what is your question? and how would you animate something which is solid black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into the visual state manager. http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/04/silverlight-introduces-visual-state-manager-vsm.aspx.

you could also handle the render loop and updating your objects in there.

http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/04/01/timers-and-the-main-game-loop.aspx